# How to run multiple scrapyd servers?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

I have been searching for documentation on the Scrapyd Service but it is very slim. I was wondering if anyone has any idea how to set up multiple Scrapyd servers that point to the same schedule queue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any 'save schedule queue', but running multiple scrapyd's is easy by opening a couple of screens and run `scrapy server`.

You can adjust the port number of a scrapyd by setting/altering the following option in your PROJECT_DIRECTORY/scrapyd.conf:

```
[scrapyd]
http_port = 6969
```

Via http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html#starting-scrapyd

Answer (score 0):

What about use the same sqlite database? The dbs_dir is set in `scrapyd.script._get_config()`.

Comment: This is a good idea but sqlite wasn't really designed for handling multiple requests from multiple servers. What I had to do was to modify the app to point to Postgresql.